# How to send jwt token from expressjs to react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, passport.js

I want to send the jwt token from the expressjs router to react application.

I using `google-passport` to login. For login, react app is redirecting it to the server and once server authenticates the user, it redirects back to the react app.

Sending token in the query is not a good option.

What are the other secure options to send the token?

Node server running on `8080` while react app is running on `3000`.

I am using `express-session` to maintain the session. Don't know if it can be used for this. And how to read this session from the react app.

Thanks

Comment: Authorization header maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the jwt as the `Authorization` header.

So, in your fetch request (or axios for that matter), just add a header like,

```
headers: {
'Authorization': `Bearer ${YourJWT}`
}
```

But for express-session, it stores the session data in the server (memory/ in-memory db like redis/ Database like MongoDB)

It sends a cookie to the client, which is returned  back by the client, and which is verified with the session data at the server. This is called as stateful authentication, as the server maintains the state of the authenticated users with it.